# NodeJs deployment on remote server

Tags: node.js, jenkins, deployment

I've an existing NodeJS application developed and the builds are running on Jenkins . Can anyone help me know on how to deploy the application on remote server and how the packaging is done for node js.

I've a requirement for automated deployment for node js application . So want to know the tools and process to do deployment . how to move forward after jenkins build .

Comment: there is a short video tutorial about how to deploy the node.js app by using shipit.js (automation tool) - https://youtu.be/8PpBySjkWEM. You can set this up on your local environment and then, move the setup to Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins and Udeploy is your key, We are currently using both to make a continuous delivery and deployment.

[nice link for git and jenkins](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511)

[another link](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/roll-your-own-node-js-ci-server-with-jenkins-part-1/)

Comment: Not sufficient , Please tell me is uDeploy freeware or paid version

Comment: Its good to include essential parts of answer then just giving a link